# How to add docker volume for zipkin server

Tags: docker, docker-volume, zipkin

I'm trying to run Zipkin server with docker but how can I store the log files? or how can I store the volume? there is no clear documentation for that.

Docker command :

```
docker run -d  -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin
```

Comment: Use `--volume` to mount your own file or directory to where the log files are

Comment: @Lissy93, but how and where is the dictionary please could you write example?